# Javascript class/ function in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects, nativescript

I am trying to move some common logic from multiple of my models in NativeScript to one seperate file that I want to require in my models. I don't have any Javascript experience and wanted to make a class like you'd do in Java however this appearantly doesn't work.

Can anybody explain what goes wrong and how I'd have to go about this?

This is what I currently have (example code):

CommonLogic.js

```
function Person(lastName, firstName)
{
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Model1.js

```
var Person = require("~/CommonLogic");

exports.loaded = function(args) {  
    var person = new Person('Clouseau', 'Jacques');
    console.log('The person is ' + person);
}
```

Error:

```
System.err: Calling js method onCreateView failed
System.err:
System.err: TypeError: Person is not a constructor
```

Comment: You need to somehow export the constructor from your CommonLogic.js module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you created the below function

```
function Person(lastName, firstName)
{
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

And then you tried to import it like below

```
var Person = require("~/CommonLogic");
```

Now image you had another class in your code `Person2`

```
function Person2(lastName, firstName)
{
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

So, now how do you import this? Would doing `var Person2 = require("~/CommonLogic");` import it Person2? That is not the way module require works. Now there are two ways to export a class/method. The ES5 way or the ES6 way

**ES5 way**

```
function Person(lastName, firstName)
{
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
}

module.exports = { Person: Person}
```

And then you can use the same in your scripts like below

```
var Person = require("~/commonlogic").Person;
```

**ES6 Way**

ES6 has a `export` keyword. So you would just do

```
export function Person(lastName, firstName)
{
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

And import could be again either ES5 or ES6

ES5 like below

```
var Person = require("~/commonlogic").Person;
```

ES6 like below

```
import {Person} from '~/commonlogic';
```